# Why does this 3rd query not return total of rows from 1st and 2nd queries?

Tags: sql-server

If the first query below returns 1377 rows and the second returns 765 rows,
why does the third query return 1806 rows instead of the expected 1377+765 = 2142 rows?

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM MyTable 
WHERE(COMMENTS LIKE '%Created by Upload #90323%')
ORDER BY item_id

SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM MyTable
WHERE (COMMENTS LIKE '%Created by Upload #90324%')
ORDER BY item_id

SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM MyTable
where (COMMENTS LIKE '%Created by Upload #90323%') 
   or (COMMENTS LIKE '%Created by Upload #90324%')
ORDER BY item_id
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because of the `DISTINCT`, there will be identical `item_id` values for both `COMMENT` values. To prove this, remove the `DISTINCT` from all queries and you will see that the number of rows will match.

Comment: Aaargh--I just figured out why I wasn't getting the expected results!  It's because of the stupid wildcard character I included at the beginning of the Comments strings!  Once I take those out, the 3rd query returns the sum of rows from the first 2 queries.